# Linux Nvidia HDMI

Tags: linux, драйвер, nvidia, hdmi

Использую ArchLinux
Неправильно отображает цвета на мониторе подключенном по HDMI

Нашел одну команду тут

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics#Weathered_colors_(color_range_problems)

```
xrandr --output <OUT> --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

но она выдает:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
Serial number of failed request:  47
Current serial number in output stream:  47
```

Comment: А как именно искажает? Может это поломка самого монитора?

Comment: нет, на windows такой проблемы нет, в ubuntu решалась через графическое приложение, которое шло вместе с драйвером.

Проблема в неправильном определение дапозона цветов (близкие цвета сливаются, например белый и серый выглядят одинаково белыми)

Comment: В Arch Linux тоже есть графическое приложение, `nvidia-settings` называется (если конечно вы установили официальный драйвер)

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз это. Помогло

Comment: Проверьте что после перезагрузки не слетает, возможно понадобиться добавить в автозагрузку команду `nvidia-settings -l`